# How to create a button that spans the entire width of the page in HTML?

Tags: html, button

```
<input type="submit" value="Go!"/>
```

gives a button like this:

[image]

I want the button to span the entire width of the page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Go!" style="width:100%"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `style="width:100%"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a hyperlink instead for this and using css to style it something like this

```css
a:hover {
  border:60px;
  border-color:blue;
  padding:30px;
  }

a {
  border:60px;
  padding:30;
  }
```

```html
<a href="link">link</a>
```